# how to implement a method add which needs a Circle object as its only parameter

Tags: java, oop

The question is to implement a method called add that uses Circle as the only parameter. The question looks like this

```
public class Circle {
    double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    // Your code for method add goes here...
  
}
```

Could someone help me to understand the add method listed below?  The question is that we need have a method that does the operation of adding a circle to another is defined as the area of the resultant circle having an area equal to the sum of areas of the original two circles. (Recall that the area of a circle is given by πr2.)

```
public class Circle {
    private double radius;
    private final double PI = Math.PI;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    // Add method

    public Circle add(Circle circle) {
        double sumOfAreas = PI * Math.pow(this.radius, 2) + PI * Math.pow(circle.radius, 2);
        this.radius = Math.sqrt(sumOfAreas / PI);
        return this.radius;
    }
}
```

i thought the add method with circle as the parameter would like something like this?

```
public add ( double circle) {
.....}
```

The class Circle should work with the main given

```
public class TestCircle {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Circle c1 = new Circle(3.5);
        Circle c2 = new Circle(6.8);
        Circle c3 = new Circle(12.9);
        
        System.out.println("Before adding,");
        System.out.println("Radius of the first circle is " + c1.getRadius());
        System.out.println("Radius of the second circle is " + c2.getRadius());
        System.out.println("Radius of the third circle is " + c3.getRadius());
        
        c1.add(c2).add(c3);
        
        System.out.println("After adding,");
        System.out.println("Radius of the first circle is " + c1.getRadius());
        System.out.println("Radius of the second circle is " + c2.getRadius());
        System.out.println("Radius of the third circle is " + c3.getRadius());
    }
}
```

and the console should print out

```
Before adding,
Radius of the first circle is 3.5
Radius of the second circle is 6.8
Radius of the third circle is 12.9
After adding,
Radius of the first circle is 14.996666296213968
Radius of the second circle is 6.8
Radius of the third circle is 12.9
```

im not entirely clear on what the add method does in the example shown, or are there other methods?

Comment: This is just mathematics. That method calculates what the targeted surface must be with the given formula (πr²) and then uses the opposite to calculate the radius that is needed to get such a surface. Just math.

Comment: You should probably add a `public double getArea()` method, and call that instead inside of `add()`. Additionally, if `add()` returns a `Circle`, how does `return this.radius;` compile and work? That should probably be `return this;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just mathematics applied in code.

It was asked to create the method `add`. I rephrase what it needs to do: it should take a Circle instance as argument, and then mutate the current Circle instance so its surface has now to the other's surface added to it.

If we perform that action as a math's exercise we could say we have two circles defined by their radi: <sub>1</sub> and <sub>2</sub>

The surface of the first circle is <sub>1</sub> and it can be calculated from its radius as:

<sub>1</sub> = π<sub>1</sub>²

And the second circle has a surface of:

<sub>2</sub> = π<sub>2</sub>²

Now we want to calculate a third radius (<sub>3</sub>) such that the corresponding surface <sub>3</sub> is the sum of the two original surfaces, i.e. <sub>1</sub> + <sub>2</sub>. So we need to solve these equations:

1. <sub>1</sub> = π<sub>1</sub>²
2. <sub>2</sub> = π<sub>2</sub>²
3. <sub>3</sub> = π<sub>3</sub>²
4. <sub>3</sub> = <sub>1</sub> + <sub>2</sub>

Given are: <sub>1</sub> and <sub>2</sub>, and asked is <sub>3</sub>.

So let's solve that:

If in equality (4) we substitute all , using the other three equalities, we derive:

π<sub>3</sub>² = π<sub>1</sub>² + π<sub>2</sub>²

...which reduces to:

<sub>3</sub>² = <sub>1</sub>² + <sub>2</sub>²

...which reduces to:

<sub>3</sub> = √(<sub>1</sub>² + <sub>2</sub>²)

The code does this in a bit overkill way, as the involvement of `PI` is not needed, but OK, it's what this code is doing.